# Login Webscraping Selenium

Tags: selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to web-scrape the following site but im stucked at login.

This is what I have been trying. Any ideas??

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Library/Chrome Drivers/chromedriver')

def site_login():

    driver.get("https://partners.rappi.com/")
    login = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'INGRESAR')]")
    user = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='1-email']")
    pass = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='auth0-lock-container- 1']/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")

    login.click()
    user.send_keys('xxx@mail.com')
    pass.send_keys('Password123')
    driver.find_element_by_id(“submit”).click()

site_login()
```

Comment: Try this to locate password `//input[@name='password']`.

Comment: @SIM Hello, what I cant get it to do, is to click the "Ingresar" button at first so I can enter user and pass. It is about this line:
    login = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'INGRESAR')]")

Comment: Needs debugging details... The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a random loading time of the web page. You need to introduce webdriverWait.

try out the below code :

**Code  :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Inc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://partners.rappi.com/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='INGRESAR']/.."))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys("abc")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "submit"))).click()
```

Comment: Would you mind helping me with the next part of my script? Im trying to open multiple rows from a table (which has multiple pages) to scrape the data but can't seem to find the way yet.

Comment: @Darkoder : I can't seem to login mate :( . I have replied to you over the new ticket that you have raised